# How to increment a variable value in select clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to pull out some statistical data and I need to cache some values and perform arithmetic operations on them to calculate the amount of money. Well imagine there're two tables, the one is for deposit history and another one is for withdrawal history.

```
DECLARE @Balance int
SET @Balance = 0;

SELECT 
      -- Plus the balance variable.
      @Balance = @Balance + VariableAmount
     ,VariableAmount
     ,TransactionDate
     ,BankCode
FROM
[dbo].[Deposit]
WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber

SELECT 
      -- Subtract the balance variable.
      @Balance = @Balance - VariableAmount
     ,VariableAmount
     ,TransactionDate
     ,BankCode
FROM
[dbo].[Withdraw]
WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
```

So if the Deposit table has 10 records and summing the `VariableAmount` up would result in $10,000, then `@Balance`'s value would be $10,000 by the time the first select statement is done. And if the Withdraw table has 5 records and summing the `VariableAmount` up would result in $3,500, then `@Balance`'s value this time, would be $6,500.

The expected result would look like this

```
From Deposit
Balance     |     VariableAmount     |     TransactionDate     |     BankCode
1,000             1,000                    2017.07.01                1
2,000             1,000                    2017.07.02                2
3,000             1,000                    2017.07.04                1
.
.
.
10,000            1,000                    2017.07.18                1

From Withdraw
Balance     |     VariableAmount     |     TransactionDate     |     BankCode
9,000             1,000                    2017.07.01                1
8,000             1,000                    2017.07.02                2
7,000             1,000                    2017.07.04                1
6,500             500                      2017.07.18                1
```

But SQLServer says when I tried to run the queries.

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Is it even possible to increment a value in a select statement? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Search for "running totals"...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: It's possible with a select if you only fill the variable.

Comment: The error message can't get any clearer.  How else can we explain it to you???  You can't combine `SELECT @var1 = column1, column2 FROM someTable`

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to increment a variable in a `select` statement.  SQL Server offers more powerful mechanisms.  From what I can tell, though, these are not needed for this question.

You can just add up two values:

```
select sum(b) as balance
from ((select sum(VariableAmount) as b
       from dbo.deposit
       where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
      ) union all
      (select - sum(VariableAmount) as b
       from dbo.withdraw
       where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
      ) 
     ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to calculate the @Balance variable?
Then just by not selecting those other fields it'll work.

```
DECLARE @Balance INT = 0;
SELECT  @Balance = @Balance + COALESCE(VariableAmount,0)
FROM [dbo].[Deposit] WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;
SELECT  @Balance = @Balance - COALESCE(VariableAmount,0)
FROM [dbo].[Withdraw] WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;
```

Making use of SUM is probably even better.

**Simplified example:**

```
-- Using table variables for the sample data
DECLARE @Deposit TABLE (AccountNumber INT, VariableAmount  INT);
INSERT INTO @Deposit (AccountNumber, VariableAmount ) VALUES 
(1,1000),(1,2000),(1,1000),(1,1000),
(2,1000),(2,2000),(2,1000);
DECLARE @Withdraw TABLE (AccountNumber INT, VariableAmount INT);
INSERT INTO @Withdraw (AccountNumber, VariableAmount) VALUES 
(1,1000),(1,2000),
(2,1000),(2,1000);

DECLARE @AccountNumber int = 1;

DECLARE @Balance int;

SELECT @Balance = SUM(VariableAmount) 
FROM @Deposit WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;

SELECT @Balance = @Balance - SUM(VariableAmount) 
FROM @Withdraw WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;

SELECT @AccountNumber AS AccountNumber, @Balance AS Balance;
```

**Returns:**

```
AccountNumber Balance
------------- -------
1             2000
```

And you could even do this in only one query.
Using a UNION ALL like in Gordon's solution.

```
DECLARE @Balance int;
SELECT @Balance = SUM(TotalAmount)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(VariableAmount) as TotalAmount
    FROM [dbo].[Deposit]
    WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(-VariableAmount)
    FROM [dbo].[Withdraw]
    WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
) q;

SELECT @AccountNumber AS AccountNumber, @Balance AS Balance;
```