# Need mysql query FIFO

Tags: mysql, fifo

please help me how to create mysql query for reporting in fifo method,

**table persediaan_source**

| id | id_barang | jumlah | harga | tanggal | id_jenis_transaksi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | 26 | 12 | 1050000 | 2022-07-15 05:55:23 | 1 |
| 90 | 26 | 8 | 0 | 2022-07-15 05:55:52 | 2 |
| 91 | 26 | 16 | 1100000 | 2022-07-15 05:56:22 | 1 |
| 95 | 26 | 10 | 0 | 2022-07-15 05:59:09 | 2 |

```
id_jenis_transaksi = 1 is Buy
id_jenis_transaksi = 2 is Use
```

i need report like this below

| id | date | remarks | buy_qty | buy_price | buy_total | use_qty | use_qty_detail | use_price | use_total | bal_qty | bal_qty_detail | bal_price | bal_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-15 05:55:23 | Buy | 12 | 1050000 | 12600000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 12 | 1050000 | 12600000 |
| 2 | 2022-07-15 05:55:52 | Use | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 8 | 1050000 | 8400000 | 4 | 4 | 1050000 | 4200000 |
| 3 | 2022-07-15 05:56:22 | Buy | 16 | 1100000 | 17600000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 4 | 1050000 | 4200000 |
| 4 | 2022-07-15 05:56:22 | Buy | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 1100000 | 17600000 |
| 5 | 2022-07-15 05:59:09 | Use | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 4 | 1050000 | 4200000 | 10 | 0 | 1050000 | 0 |
| 6 | 2022-07-15 05:59:09 | Use | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1100000 | 6600000 | 0 | 10 | 1100000 | 11000000 |

in row #3 must be breakdown in **bal_qty_detail** because there is a different price and have a remaining qty from a previous price, also in row #5 must be breakdown in **use_qty_detail**

```
CREATE TABLE `persediaan_source` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_barang` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jumlah` double NOT NULL,
  `harga` double NOT NULL,
  `tanggal` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id_jenis_transaksi` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id = 1 -> buy, id = 2 -> use'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `persediaan_source` (`id`, `id_barang`, `jumlah`, `harga`, `tanggal`, `id_jenis_transaksi`) VALUES
(89, 26, 12, 1050000, '2022-07-15 05:55:23', 1),
(90, 26, 8, 0, '2022-07-15 05:55:52', 2),
(91, 26, 16, 1100000, '2022-07-15 05:56:22', 1),
(95, 26, 10, 0, '2022-07-15 05:59:09', 2);
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154592/calculate-quantity-based-on-first-in-first-out-fifo) could help

Comment: I've tried that link before I asked for this help, the link doesn't match what I need, on the link it doesn't show the price

Comment: What is the logic for row 4 and 6? Why are columns 0 in row-4 and 6. Use related column=0 in row for buy is understandable, but in this case almost all columns are 0!

Comment: I think this report has a problem in terms of logic. Rule to generate report is not clear.

Comment: It can be achieved by using variables, Kindly refer the given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391820/how-to-increment-a-variable-value-in-select-clause-in-sql-server).

Comment: @NandanRana, how do you create extra rows than available rows/

Comment: I suggest you do it in application code.  SQL is quite messy when iterating through rows; it would prefer to work on all the rows at once.

Answer (score 1):

Hi using the below process you can achieve the mention reporting format. But to handle the granularity of fifo you should aviod creating these logic in mysql.

```
SELECT @bal_qty:=0,@old_qty:=0,@old_qty_price:=0,@new_qty:=0,@new_qty_price:=0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test1
SELECT id, tanggal as date, 
@remarks:=if(id_jenis_transaksi=1,'Buy','Use') as remarks, 
@buy_qty:=if(id_jenis_transaksi=1,jumlah,0) as buy_qty, 
@buy_price:=if(id_jenis_transaksi=1,harga,0) as buy_price,  
@buy_total:=(@buy_qty * @buy_price) as buy_total, 
@use_qty:=if(id_jenis_transaksi=2,jumlah,0) as use_qty, 
@use_qty_detail:=if(@remarks='Use',if(@old_qty>0,@old_qty, @use_qty),0) as use_qty_detail, 
@use_price:=@old_qty_price as use_price, 
@use_total:=(@use_qty * @use_price) as use_total, 
@bal_qty:=if(@remarks='Buy',@bal_qty + @buy_qty, if(@bal_qty>@use_qty,@bal_qty - @use_qty, @bal_qty)) as bal_qty, 
@old_qty:=if(@old_qty > 0, @old_qty, if(@remarks='Use',@bal_qty, @old_qty)) as old_qty,
@old_qty_price:=if(@old_qty_price > 0, @old_qty_price, @buy_price) as old_qty_price,  
@new_qty:=if(@old_qty>0,@buy_qty, if(@new_qty>0, @new_qty,0)) as new_qty,
@new_qty_price:=if(@old_qty_price > 0 and @buy_price > 0, @buy_price, if(@new_qty_price>0,@new_qty_price,0)) as new_qty_price,
@bal_qty_detail:=if(@old_qty > 0, @old_qty, @buy_qty) as bal_qty_detail, 
@bal_price:=@old_qty_price as bal_price,
@bal_total:=(@bal_qty_detail* @old_qty_price) as bal_total,
@split_flag:=if(@bal_qty != @buy_qty and @bal_qty != @old_qty,1,0) as split_flag 
FROM persediaan_source;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 select * from test1 where split_flag=1

SELECT @cnt:=0;

SELECT (@cnt:=@cnt + 1) as id, date, remarks, buy_qty, buy_price, buy_total, use_qty, use_qty_detail, use_price, use_total, bal_qty, bal_qty_detail, bal_price, bal_total 
FROM (
     (SELECT * FROM test1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, date, remarks, 0 as buy_qty, 0 as buy_price, 0 as buy_total, 0 as use_qty, 
@used_qty:=(use_qty - use_qty_detail) as use_qty_detail, 
if(remarks='Use',@new_qty_price,0) as use_price, 
(@used_qty * new_qty_price)  as use_total, 0 as bal_qty, 0 as old_qty, 
0 as old_qty_price, 0 as new_qty,0 as new_qty_price, 
@bal_qty_detail:=if(remarks='Buy', buy_qty,  bal_qty) as bal_qty_detail, 
new_qty_price as bal_price, 
(@bal_qty_detail * new_qty_price) as bal_total, split_flag 
 FROM test2)
) as t order by 2
```

Comment: The OP has mentioned the table, data and required output. I highly suggest you to give the solution rather than some suggestions

Comment: Asgar is it what you were expecting.

Comment: can you also put create table and insert data queries?

Comment: @Asgar for base table i.e (persediaan_source) i have used the same create table and insert query mentioned in problem statement. In my solution i have created temporary table and instead of insert I have used select to store the output of query for futher use. I had to create test2 table, As test1 was temporary table and you can't reuse same temporary table in union query.